# Adding a GPU to an HP laptop

Tags: laptop, gpu

I am considering to buy a new HP laptop. I intend to install Ubuntu and use it mostly for office works, but, I also want to practice high-end parallel computations on a GPU (e.g. cryptocoin mining. My question is: is it possible to add a custom number of GPUs to an existing HP laptop?

Comment: No. Also, crypto mining on a laptop, really?

Comment: Crypto mining on private computers is useless nowadays.

Comment: @harrymc it depends which coin you mine. In any case, I am only doing this for learning purposes.

Comment: Have fun, but your electricity bill may be more than your gains.

Answer (score 0):

You could research external gps (see https://www.google.com.au/amp/s/www.pcworld.com/article/2984716/laptop-computers/how-to-transform-your-laptop-into-a-gaming-powerhouse-with-an-external-graphics-card.amp.html) and see if they might work with your laptop.

Though, it would be easier to just buy a gaming laptop.